# How to calculate a numpy.dot() product of two large matrix without calculating part of the result matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Suppose we have two matrix a = [[1, 2][3, 4]], b = [[5, 6][7, 8]] (in my case they are very large). Using numpy.dot(a,b), we can get the result as res = [[19, 22],[43, 50]]. If in the result, we only need part of the elements, i.e [[19,NA],[NA,50]], and we don't care about 22 or 43. How could I implement such numpy dot product with knowing which part of result matrix I want (in my example it is mask = [[1, 0][0, 1]])?

The actual result mask is a random csr_matrix.

In general, we have two large matrix A (size: M x N) and B (size: N x P). And in the numpy.dot() result, we only care about elements that is 1 in mask M (size: M x P). So we'd like to improve the performance by skipping those elements in the mask that is 0.

Comment: I think the answer will depend on the structure of the desired elements.  You gave an example where you want just the diagonal of the product.  Is that typical of your desired output?

Comment: Thanks for asking! The result mask is a csr_matrix with random structures.

Comment: I tested a sparse version of the linked answer, and compared it with `Ms.multiply(As*Bs)` (with 3 sparse  matrices).  For my small case the direct  case is faster.  `As[I,:].multiply(Bs[:,J].T).sum(1)`  involves 3 more sparse matrix products - to do the row/col indexing and to do the row sum.  But the alternatives might scale differently.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` sparse as well, or just `M`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) and then the usual numpy dot product:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
a = ma.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]], mask=[[0,1],[1,0]])
b = ma.array([[5, 6],[7, 8]], mask=[[0,1],[1,0]])  

np.dot(a,b)


masked_array(data =
 [[19 --]
 [-- 50]],
             mask =
 [[False  True]
 [ True False]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: What if the result mask is a random csr_matrix? Thanks!

Comment: the execution time is the same.

Comment: THe masked `dot` still calculates the hidden values.  Check the `np.dot(a,b).data`.  `np.ma` arrays don't save time or memory.

Comment: `np.ma` does not work with `sparse.csr_matrix`.

Comment: His original qsn didn't mention csr matrix.